# SCJP assert statement

Tags: java, scjp

This question is from SCJP dumps. May be it seems stupid , but i have a bit confusion about options. please help me out

> public class Donkey2 {
>
> ```
>    public static void main(String[] args) {
>
>     boolean assertsOn = true;
>
>     assert (assertsOn) : assertsOn = true;
>
>            if(assertsOn) {
>
>                      System.out.println("assert is on");
>
>                          }
>
>           }
> ```
>
> }

If class Donkey is invoked twice, the first time without assertions enabled, and the second time with
assertions enabled, what are the results?

A. no output

B. no output ; assert is on

C. assert is on

D. no output ; An AssertionError is thrown.

E. assert is on ; An AssertionError is thrown

Answer ) if i invoke it twice i will get 
          assert is on
          assert is on

Is that true?

Book says answer is C) but i guess it should be twice i.e. assert is on ; assert is on in both cases

Comment: What happened when you ran it?

Comment: right now i dont have a compiler to enable and disable assert.

Answer (score 1):

To the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.10) we go

> If the value is true, no further action is taken and the assert
>   statement completes normally.
>
> If the value is false, the execution behavior depends on whether
>   Expression2 is present:
>
> - If Expression2 is present, it is evaluated.
>
>   - If the evaluation completes abruptly for some reason, the assert statement completes abruptly for the same reason.
>   - If the evaluation completes normally, an AssertionError instance whose "detail message" is  the resulting value of Expression2 is
>       created.
>   - If the instance creation completes abruptly for some reason, the assert statement completes abruptly for the same reason.
>   - If the instance creation completes normally, the assert statement completes abruptly by throwing the newly created AssertionError
>       object.

If assertion is disabled, the `assert` is skipped, `assertsOn` is `true`, so the `if` block is executed.

If assertion is enabled, the `assert` is executed, `assertsOn` is `true`, so assertion passes. `assertsOn` is `true`, so the `if` block is executed.

The answer is what you say it is.

```
assert is on ; assert is on
```

There might be something you aren't telling/showing us or the answers presented there are missing the correct one.

Comment: This is purely subjective but (C) means , "assert is on" is printed for both the choices,because if you look at the options(A,B,C,D,E) two choices are only for the options which have different choices .Similarly option (A) means no Output for both cases